# Add value to a db context table - column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to pass 'the name of the person who modified the record. I got that on my addedBy variable but not sure how to pass it to the context.tableName.column name.

```
using (var context = new MyEntities())
{
       var result = context.MyTableName.Where(x => x._ID == paramId).FirstOrDefault();
                    
       if (result != null)
       {
           var addedBy = User.Identity.Name;
           context.MyTableName.Add(addedBy);
           context.MyTableName.Remove(result);
           context.SaveChanges();
       }

       return Json(new
                   {
                       data = result,
                       JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                   });
}
```

Comment: @mxmissile, my bad for the confusion all I need is to pass the addedBy variable to MyTable AddedBy column. skip the Remove result part.

Comment: @mxmissile that's all I needed. Thank you :-)

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `Remove()` call, and set the AddedBy property:

`result.AddedBy = addedBy;`

Then call `SaveChanges()`.